# how to split huge DBF file?

Tags: sybase, visual-foxpro, foxpro, dbf, advantage-database-server

The task is to split huge DBF file from very old ERP system.

Size of the files are:
table1.dbf - 5307 MB
table1.cdx - 288 MB
table1.fpt - 617 MB

I do not understand how it worked on 32-bit windows... but it works.

Have you an idea how to split the table for 2 files?

for example 10% of last records in one file and 90% of oldest records in another file.

It is better to complete the task in the my environment (Win10 64 bit).

Comment: You can split using commands like copy to ... for (or while). Or select * from .. where into .... However, are you sure of those numbers? Not realistic.

Comment: could oou offer me any FREE sql mananger to do it?

Comment: Yes VFPOLEDB is distributed for free. You can use it with any language like C#, Go, T-SQL ...

Comment: thanks for the answer. I tryed this connection string: Provider=vfpoledb;Data Source=C:\temp\3\archivbz.dbf. And when I try to establish connection as the result I get error "Invalid seek offset". Have you any idea?

Comment: Connection string should be: Provider=vfpoledb;Data Source=C:\temp\3 but with any file over 2 Gb I don't expect it to be read successfully. You are saying it works, maybe it is using 64 bit driver from ADS? I would personally split that low-level using something like C# or Go (but that requires a good knowledge of dbf, fpt structures - I have done that but not an easy task).

Comment: yes, I can establish connection now. But when I try to open dataset then I have the same error.

Answer (score 3):

The bottom line here is that if table1.dbf is > 2GB then it was not Visual FoxPro that was working with it, and the Visual Foxpro OLEDB driver will not be able to read it.

it is more likely to have been [SAP's Advantage Database Server](https://archive.sap.com/documents/docs/DOC-39207)

So I would investigate getting hold of an ODBC\OLEDB driver for that and using it to extract data.

Comment: looks like you are quite right. I can open the table in Advantage Data Architect. But as previously I can not find the way to execute any SQL or at main point how to split the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
USE table1
```

Locate the row which you want split from *(you will get split from the located record to the last record)*

```
COPY TO table2 REST
```

Make sure the **table2** has been generated.  If **table2** has been created, then locate the same row in **table1** again.

```
DELETE REST
```